# Starting thread after thread is finished

Tags: python, multithreading

Lets say I want to run 10 threads at same time and after one is finished start immediately new one. How can I do that?

I know with `thread.join()` I can wait to get finished, but than 10 threads needs to be finished, but I want after one finished to start new one immediately.

Comment: I suggest you use either something called a [`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool) which will take care of things automatically, **or** the more modern [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor).

Comment: Creating and destroying threads is expensive. The "ThreadPool" that Martineau told you about is a way of re-using threads. You want to start task B immediately after task A is complete? Instead of letting one thread die, and then starting another, it would be more efficient if one thread could perform both tasks in sequence. A `ThreadPool` is an object that more or less automatically does that  for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I understand is that you need to execute 10 thread at the same time.

I suggest you to use `threading.BoundedSemaphore()`

A sample code on using it is given below:

```py
import threading
from typing import List


def do_something():
    print("I hope this cleared your doubt :)")


sema4 = threading.BoundedSemaphore(10)
# 10 is given as parameter since your requirement stated that you need just 10 threads to get executed parallely

threads_list: List[threading.Thread] = []
# Above variable is used to save threads

for i in range(100):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
    threads_list.append(thread)  # saving thread in order to join it later
    thread.start()  # starting the thread

for thread in threads_list:
    thread.join() # else, parent program is terminated without waiting for child threads
```